# DB Navigator - Operation not supported (intellij IDEA)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

When I want to add a new table in `IntelliJ IDEA` by right click and choose `New Table..`;

[image: add table in intellij]

I encounter this error

[image: DB Navigator - Operation not supported]

It says that the operation of creating a new table is not supported yet. I'm using MySql for the database. But, when I'm watching some youtube tutorials, they have that feature, but I don't have it.

What can I do next ?? reinstall ??